# DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") shows in dd.mm.yyyy format after publishing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I write `txtChallanDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`
It shows ok, but after publishing in server (IIS), the date shows in dd.mm.yyyy format

Comment: publish where ? In azure / vm / localhost ?

Comment: IIS in windows server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")
```

`/` is  a separator character and the replaced character in `ToString` culture dependent. If you want the literal `/` character you must escape it with single quotes. Alternatively you can supply a `CultureInfo` instance to the `ToString` method.

Example [Stackblitz](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T0BL0Y)